# How to leave only the lower border of UITextField?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

It is necessary to leave only the bottom border at UITextField. For some reason my code does not work.

```
let bottomLine = CALayer()
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:1.0, width: myTextField.frame.width, 
height: myTextField.frame.height - 1)
bottomLine.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.None
myTextField.layer.addSublayer(bottomLine)
```

Comment: What is not working? What is the code doing and what is the expected output? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
 bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:1.0, width: myTextField.frame.width,height: myTextField.frame.height - 1)
```

with

```
bottomLine.frame = CGRect(x:0.0, y:myTextField.frame.height - 1, width: myTextField.frame.width,height: 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case work with adding :

```
myTextFeld.wantsLayer = true
```